# Can more energy be extracted from a system of minimum free energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

As far as I know, systems tend to minimize their free energy. The free energy is to my knowledge a measure of "useful" energy of a system. So my question is: Is it possible for a system to be in a state of minimum but non-vanishing free energy? If that is possible, can one couple this system and further reduce its free energy?

Comment: For three blocks A, B, and C at different temperatures, one can place A and B together, allow them to come to thermal equilibrium (so that the associated free energy is minimized), and then run a heat engine between A+B and C to extract energy. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: @Chemomechanics kind of. What I was thinking of is for example the harmonic oscillator. I saw some calculations that even when thermalized it has a finite non vanishing free energy. Would it somehow be possible to extract the remaining free energy by coupling it to another system and varying a parameter cyclically?